# Move Custom Posts to Normal Posts

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a Wordpress website which has some articles in a Custom Post Type called "Editorial". Is there a way to move these articles to normal ones under the Category called "Editorial"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there definitely is... and it's really painless.  Check out this great plugin called "Post Type Switcher".  Once you switch the post type you will be able to categorize it as normal.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-type-switcher/